# C# & SQL Server : parse Excel range into data table but data table returning as empty

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am trying to save values from an excel range to a data table. I am then parsing my data table into a stored procedure to save into the database.

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Territory", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("OptionID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ProductClass", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Taken", typeof(string));

for (var idx = 7; idx < lastUsedRow; idx++)
{
    string Territory = territory;
    string optionID = ((string)Worksheet.Range["B" + idx].Value2);
    string ProductClass = ((string)Worksheet.Range["C" + idx].Value2);
    string Taken = ((string)Worksheet.Range["V" + idx].Value2);
}

dt.Rows.Add(optionID, Territory, ProductClass, Taken) //this is an issue it returns dt{}
```

SQL:

```
var connectionstring2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SDYConString"].ConnectionString;
var cn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring2);

cn2.Open();

var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_ui_sm_insertrows", cn2);

SqlParameter tvparam = cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
var da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);

cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn2.Close();
```

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ui_sm_insertrows]
    @dt AS tbl_type_lines READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_newline (TERRITORY, OPTION_ID, PRODUCT_CLASS, TAKEN)
        SELECT 
            TERRITORY, OPTION_ID, PRODUCT_CLASS, TAKEN
        FROM @dt;
END
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OPTION_ID', table '@dt'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The data for table-valued parameter "@dt" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.
>
> SQL Server error is: 515, state: 2 The statement has been terminated.

The `dt {}` seems to be empty so it doesn't insert anything in it. When I go into debug mode there is a value in option ID variable - is this the correct way to insert the rows into the datatable? I need to map the created columns and rows together then parse into my stored procedure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Don't you think you are not adding anything to dt? You have a loop and the variables are scoped to that loop. After the loop, you have an .Add(...) - and also there OptionId, Territory seems to be reversed.

Comment: Instead of such an SP, I would use SqlBulkCopy class to directly load from Excel to SQL Server.